# Adding 8 bit numbers in two registers (8 bit as well, 16 bit not allowed to use)

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm doing a homework where I need to add x numbers of 8 bits and the result has to be stored in two registers (in case of overflow). How can I set the result in two registers? (I fill the data using memory)

Sorry I'm new in assembly, any guidance is well welcome.

So far I have added the numbers yet the result is stored in one register.

```
org 100
Mov al,[0x0300]
Mov ah,[0x0301]
xor dh,dh
add dh,al
add dh,ah
```

I'd wish that the result stores in two registers instead of one (So results above 8 bits can be stored).

Comment: When you do an add, other than the destination register, what else gets changed?  Can you use that to figure out what to do with your second result register?

Comment: Second register have to store part of the result if the addition overflow the 8 bit size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> org 100
> Mov al,[0x0300]
> Mov ah,[0x0301]
> xor dh,dh
> add dh,al
> add dh,ah
> ```

You need to take care of the carry that arises from the addition of the 2 byte-sized values:

First clear the 2 registers that will hold the result

```
xor al, al
xor ah, ah
```

Then add all of the values that you need to process:

```
add al, [0x0300]
adc ah, 0

add al, [0x0301]
adc ah, 0
```

It's the `ADC` (Add with Carry) instruction that deals with the propagated carry!

You can avoid the separate step of clearing in the above code with:

```
mov al, [0x0300]
xor ah, ah

add al, [0x0301]
adc ah, 0
```

Comment: So, for example if [0x0300] contains FF and [0x0301] also contain FF, does al and ah will carry the total result ? (Like using ax instead?)

Comment: @PepoPapo With those values you'll get `AL=0xFE` and `AH=0x01`. Same as `AX=0x01FE`.

Comment: Thank you soo much!